# awk printing every nth matched line and all lines not math

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I know how to print every nth line and nth matched line, but don't know how to print every nth matched line and all lines not math.

Input example:

```
Something else 1
Downloading: file1 1%
Downloading: file1 10%
Something else 2
Downloading: file1 30%
Something else 3
Downloading: file1 40%
Downloading: file2 50%
Downloading: file1 60%
Downloading: file1 100%
Downloading: file2 100%
Something else 4
```

If pattern is '^Downloading:' and print every 2nd matched line, output should like this:

```
Something else 1
Downloading: file1 10%
Something else 2
Something else 3
Downloading: file1 40%
Downloading: file1 60%
Downloading: file2 100%
Something else 4
```

Comment: show the input fragment nd the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '!(/Downloading/ && ++c%2)' file
Something else 1
Downloading: file1 10%
Something else 2
Something else 3
Downloading: file1 40%
Downloading: file1 60%
Downloading: file2 100%
Something else 4
```

Comment: great stuff! For the title: "Prints **each second** line which matches `/Downloading/`"

Answer (score 0):

For the perl fans:

```
perl -nlE 'say unless /Downloading/ && ++$n%2'
```